# Not able to change foreground of label in ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, listboxitem

Below is the sample code of my WPF xaml file. My intention is to change the foreground of the label in the listboxitem to Red colour when the item is selected. However, no changes was seen on the foreground? What mistake had I done?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="WishlistListBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#282C2F"/>

            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                        
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                    <Border x:Name="WishlistBorder" Style="{DynamicResource WishlistBorderContent}">
                                        <ContentPresenter />
                                    </Border>
                                    
                                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                                        <Style x:Key="WishlistBorderContent" TargetType="Border">
                                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 2"/>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#50D3D3D3"/>
                                        </Style>
                                        
                                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="WishlistBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                                            <Setter TargetName="WishlistBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#63C5DA"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="WishlistBorder" Property="Background" Value="#50D3D3D3"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SymbolList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSymbol}" 
     Style="{StaticResource WishlistListBoxStyle}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="200" Padding="0">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding}" Foreground="White"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                
</ListBox>
```

Comment: The so-called local value `Foreground="White"` on the Label in the DataTemplate has higher value precedence than a value set by a Style Setter. See [Dependency property value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netdesktop-6.0)

Comment: @Clemens I had removed the local value ```Foreground="White"```, but it still not wroking.

Comment: This should work now. I tried your ListBoxItemStyle and it works with a TextBlock in the DataTemplate instead of a Label.

Comment: For a Label, write `<Label Content="{Binding}" Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"/>`

Comment: Amazing, the second solution works for me. Thank!

Comment: Note that for displaying text you would use a TextBlock, not a Label.